# MongoDB find returns nothing

Tags: mongodb

I'm starting learning and using MongoDB. I'm following a basic sample consisting creating a collection with one document. So I first switched to a test db using `use testdb`.
Then I executed this command in order to insert a new document into a new collection:

```
db.websites.insert({ name: "homepage", _id: "http://www.html.it", tags: ["Development", "Design", "System"]});
```

This command returned to me: `WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })`

Finally I wanna show the last inserted document using

```
db.website.find()
```

But, (and this is the problem), it returns me nothing!! No errors, no documents...

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: perhaps: db.websites.find()

Comment: Yes, it is! The Beginner guide has an error! Thank a lot and sorry for the trivial question! :) @chf

Answer (score 1):

apparently your insertion is correctly done (it's indicated by the output in the shell). To do your test correctly, you have to

1. Create a collection : `db.createCollection('collectionName');`
2. Use this collectionn : `use collectionName;`
3. Insert some data inside : `db.websites.insert({ name: "homepage", _id: "http://www.html.it", tags: ["Development", "Design", "System"]});`
4. Use the command find : `db.websites.find();`

To find a result, be sure you're using the correct collection before do the command find.

Answer (score 0):

As understood by @chf ,the collection name in `db.website.find()` command was wrong: the correct one is `websites` (with the s).

So the [Begineer Guide](http://www.html.it/pag/52462/la-shell-e-le-operazioni-crud/) contains an error.

Thanks to all and sorry for the trivial question.